# What's wrong with my Closure compiled sourcemap?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, google-closure, firefox-developer-tools

I compiled a small test with Closure as described [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/):

Using `java -jar compiler.jar --js test.js --create_source_map ./test-min.js.map --source_map_format=V3 --js_output_file test-min.js` I have:

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="doodle" height="200" width="200"></canvas>

<script src="test-min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS test-min.js:

```
(function(){for(var b=document.getElementById("doodle").getContext("2d"),a=0;100>a;a++)b.fillStyle="rgb(200,0,0,0.1",b.fillRect(10*a,10,55,50*a),b.fillStyle="rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.1)",b.fillRect(30,30*a,55,50*a)})();
//# sourceMappingURL=test-min.js.map
```

JS test-min.js.map:

```
{
"version":3,
"file":"test-min.js",
"lineCount":1,
"mappings":"AAAC,SAAQ,EAAG,CAEV,IADD,IAAIA,EAAMC,QAAAC,eAAA,CAAwB,QAAxB,CAAAC,WAAA,CAA6C,IAA7C,CAAV,CACUC,EAAE,CAAX,CAAgB,GAAhB,CAAcA,CAAd,CAAqBA,CAAA,EAArB,CACCJ,CAAAK,UAIA,CAJgB,iBAIhB,CAHAL,CAAAM,SAAA,CAAc,EAAd,CAAiBF,CAAjB,CAAoB,EAApB,CAAwB,EAAxB,CAA4B,EAA5B,CAA+BA,CAA/B,CAGA,CADAJ,CAAAK,UACA,CADgB,sBAChB,CAAAL,CAAAM,SAAA,CAAc,EAAd,CAAkB,EAAlB,CAAqBF,CAArB,CAAwB,EAAxB,CAA4B,EAA5B,CAA+BA,CAA/B,CAPS,CAAX,CAAA;",
"sources":["test.js"],
"names":["ctx","document","getElementById","getContext","i","fillStyle","fillRect"]
}
```

all in the same folder. However, neither Firefox nor Chrome devtools will show uncompiled source from the sourcemap. Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug in the latest Closure compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files look OK to me, and I just tried this with the latest Closure Compiler without problems. Since you didn't mention these two things in your question, you should verify the following:

- Make sure that the original .js file, test.js is in the same directory. The source map tells the browser how to map lines in the minified/compiled file to the original source -- but it still needs the original source.
- Make sure that  JavaScript source map support in enabled. In Chrome, look for **JavaScript source map support** Under **Sources** in the Settings. In Firefox, check "Show original sources" in the Debugger options.

If you have those things set up, it should work correctly. Note that you can still see the contents of the minified file if you go into the sources panel and click on the `min.js` file. However, if you set a breakpoint in the *non-minified* file, it should work correctly.

Likewise, if you have an exception in your code (and you have break on exception turned on), when you enter the debugger, it should show where the exception occurred in the *non-minified* code.

See also:

- [Source Maps](http://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#source-maps)  in the Chrome DevTools docs.
- [Use a source map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger#Use_a_source_map) in the Firefox Developer Tools docs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So it requires original js file too? Isn't that kinda cheating?

Comment: Were you hoping that all the sources were encoded in the source map?

Comment: Yeah - why use .map when devtools just switches from viewing/using the minified, to full versions?

Comment: Chrome is running the minified version for _everyone_. So all of your users get the advantages of the smaller download.

IF you debug the page with DevTools (or another debugger that supports source maps), it pulls the source map and the full versions of the files as well. It's still running the minified code, but it shows you breakpoints, etc., in the full version.

Comment: Including the sources in the source maps was [implemented in 2017](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/issues/1890#issuecomment-282772095).